# Helm charts - Install both individual chart and umbrella chart independently

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We have a bunch of services, say 10 in number that would deploy independently, each with its own helm chart. They are released from Azure DevOps pipeline.

Now, when setting up a new environment, Helm umbrella feels like a good way to deploy all these 10 services with just one `helm upgrade --install uat all-apps -n uat-myapp-ns` (release name uat) instead of each app like `helm upgrade --install uat-app-1 app-1 -n uat-myapp-ns` (release name uat-app-1) etc.

With that, we restructured the individual charts to sit inside the umbrella under the charts folder like so:

```
all-apps
├── charts
│   ├── app-1
│   │   ├── 
│   │   ├── 
│   ├── app-2
│   │   ├── 
│   │   ├── 
│   │   └── 
│   └── Chart.yaml
│   └── values.yaml
```

The related problem now is that each app cannot be upgraded individually.

`helm upgrade --install uat-app-1 app-1` throws the error

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ConfigMap "uat-app-1-env" in namespace "uat-myapp-ns" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "uat-app-1": current value is "uat"
```

I wouldn't want to uninstall the uat umbrella release before installing uat-app-1 release because that removes the other 9 services not upgraded.

Once in the umbrella way of doing things, does Helm need individual apps to be only applied via the umbrella?

[Conditions and tags](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/dependencies/#conditions-and-tags) might be an option, but I thought of asking before changing all the apps over.

Comment: Tried conditions now and it isn't helpful in upgrading individual child charts. Same with tags. The unbrella chart has all apps as dependencies and marking a dependency with condition or tag and then upgrading with only app-1 condition set uninstalls all other charts. I would like to have other child charts unaffected with the upgrade of one of the child charts.

Comment: The way we usually approach this - externalize all configuration prone to frequent changes (mainly, image versions and few other things) to the main values.yaml, then you should be able to have custom values yaml files to trigger configurations you want.

Now, if at some point that becomes too much of values to manage, there are tools to manage this, i.e. Reliza Hub that we're building.

Comment: The issue isn't with the values file itself, but once an umbrella is built, it doesn't appear that I can deploy only subset of dependent charts without uninstalling the other charts. Deploying the entire umbrella every time will cause services (child chart) not planned to be deployed to also be affected.

Comment: Usually, you can add "enabled" flag for each subchart, which would be controlled by if statements within. Then simply toggle enabled true / false in the umbrella's values file. I.e. see here for a sample of auxiliary charts using enabled flag - https://github.com/relizaio/helm-charts/

Comment: Referred the repo, thanks and tried with if condition. The child chart not enabled gets uninstalled on running helm upgrade. My need is to be able to leave the other 9 charts unaffected if only one chart is upgraded. Helm umbrella seems to be replacing all charts with the new configuration.